# Remove a word if it contains a specific letter

Tags: python, string, pandas

Let's say I have a string like

```
test = "hello Everyone! My name is Dan."
```

I want to make a function that removes all the words containing a specific letter like `!`

Then my string would be

```
"hello My name is Dan."
```

I tried this by `test.split(' ')`, and replace it with `''` if it contains the specific letter. However, since I have quite long documents, it seems to be a little inefficient.

Is there any other simple and compact way of solving this?

Thanks in advance! =]

Comment: As you have included the `pandas` tag in the question, make sure to include a sample of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this over a lot of entries in a series, you can do the following:

```
df['ser'] = df['ser'].str.replace(r'\w+[!.,]', '')
```

This will replace any word following any character inside the square brackets with a blank, and is a good vectorized approach for a Pandas series.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way you are doing this is the fastest way, but you might want to use some faster keywords in it. Try this:

```
test = "hello Everyone! My name is Dan."
words = test.split(" ")
words = [word for word in words if not "!" in word]
answer = " ".join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 methods, `split` and `join` together. So basically your function is one line only (the return statement).

```
  def removeChar(string , char):
      return "".join(string.split(char)) 

  result = removeChar("hello Everyone! My name is Dan.",'!')
  print (result)
```

Is this part of your homework? Don't cheat man, try yourself and only come here when You at least have tried ;)

Also I recommend You to use REPL, a superb great real time online interpreter for Python and other languages. Check this solution there

https://repl.it/@inGodwetrust/RealisticStridentMatch

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list and put your specific letter in it and then use a for to replace it with space. like this:

```py
specific_chars = [';', ':', '!', "*"] 

test = "hello Everyone! My name is Dan."

for i in specific_chars : 
    test_string = test.replace(i, '') 

print(test_string)
```

Answer (score -1):

use the replace method for the string i.e`txt = "hello Everyone! My name is Dan."

x = txt.replace("Everyone!", "")

print(x)
`

Comment: This is not dynamic, as in it won't work for something like `txt = 'Hey there!'` you will return `Hey there!` but it should return `Hey`

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks. Should be a regex that will match the character for the string